# difference between elastic and scalable expenditure model

Tags: azure, cost-management

I am going through exam questions, where in I find some questions are quite tricky. Where in I got a question in mind, what is difference between elastic and scaleble expenditure model?

The question arrived due to below two questions.
Your company is planning to migrate all their virtual machines to an Azure pay-as-you-go subscription. The virtual machines are currently hosted on the Hyper-V hosts in a data center.
You are required make sure that the intended Azure solution uses the correct expenditure model.
Solution: You should recommend the use of the elastic expenditure model.
Does the solution meet the goal?
•   A. Yes B . No  Ans ; No ( B)
B is the correct answer. The correct expenditure model is "Operational".

Your company is planning to migrate all their virtual machines to an Azure pay-as-you-go subscription. The virtual machines are currently hosted on the Hyper-V hosts in a data center.
You are required make sure that the intended Azure solution uses the correct expenditure model.
Solution: You should recommend the use of the scalable expenditure model.
Does the solution meet the goal?
A. Yes B . No      Ans : No(B)

so how to differentiate scalable and operational?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalability is simply an increase in size or number—and, therefore, Elastic is also a form of scaling, but in this case within the same machine.

For example, we have two types of scaling:

- **HORIZONTAL SCALING (known as Elastic model):** Increase memory and storage (etc.) of a VM as the workload increases and reduces accordingly.
- **VERTICAL SCALING (scalable expenditure model):** Increase by adding or attaching more virtual machines of the same size and configuration.

***Note:*** Memory and storage of the same VM are increased IN Elastic models WHILE new VMs are added in SCALABLE MODELS. Either way, just know that the number of VMs remain the same, but memory/storage increases in the 'elastic model' and number of VMs increases as well as memory/storage.

Comment: I think you mixed them up. They are exavtly the opposite.

Answer (score 8):

- Scalable : environments only care about increasing capacity to accommodate an increasing workload.
- Elastic : environments care about being able to meet current demands without under/over provisioning, in an autonomic fashion.

Scalable systems don't necessarily mean they will scale back down - it's only about being able to reach peak loads.
Elastic workloads, however, will recognize dynamic demands and adapt to them, even if that means reducing capacity.

Operating expenditures are ongoing costs of doing business. Consuming cloud services in a pay-as-you-go model could qualify as an operating expenditure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/strategy/business-outcomes/fiscal-outcomes

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a "decoy" question that may be phrased as a 4-way multiple choice question in the real exam. The correct answer is 'operational expenditure' since you pay for what you use. The other possibility is 'capital expenditure' (which is wrong since you are not investing in assets). 'scalable' and 'elastic' expenditure are nonsense terms put in to distract you if you are just guessing.